# Testing permutations python

Tags: python

I need some help starting this please as I've just been staring at this blankly for quite a while now

```
from itertools import permutations
import numpy as np


limit = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)

a = ?
b = ?
c = ?
```

My intention is to iterate through each permutation of (a, b, c) where each is a value within in the limit. So I can test a function I'm working with to find the best possible outcome

Comment: What problems have you faced so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty direct application of the permutations iterator

```
limit = np.arange(0,1,0.01)
for a,b,c in permutations(limit,3):
    # do something with a, b, and c
```

The `permutations` function will go through all 3 item permutations of the values in `limit` and assign those values to `a`,`b`, and `c`.

Make sure that you realize that there are quite a few permutations to loop through.  As `limit` consists of 100 values, there will be 970,200 individual permutations, so if the operations you wish to do with these values take much time, your code might take a while to run.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) in the official python documentation for details on the permutations function.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was after. I just for the life of me couldn't figure out how to put it all together